# Adding numeric figures over a barchart graph in R

Tags: r, graph, plot

I was trying to add numbers over the barchart in R.

Below is my code, but I how can I place the numbers at the center, top of each bar?

```
> F <- c(2, 4, 5, 7, 4)
> barplot(F, main="Report Freqencies", xlab="Freqencies", ylab="Number", ylim=c(0,10), names.arg=c("Daily","Weekly","Monthly", "Quarterly", "Semi-Annual"), border="dark green", density=c(70, 70, 70, 70, 70)) 

> text(F, labels = format(F,5), pos = 3, cex = 0.75)
```

My code results in the figures being scattered.

Comment: What do you mean by "figures"? Do you mean numeric digits or images?

Comment: yes, sorry for confusing. numerica digits

Answer (score 0):

Several plots (e.g., `barplot` and `boxplot`) actually return a value (invisibly) after creating the graphic. If you want to see if a particular function you are using returns something of use, you should read the help documentation on it. In this case, `help(barplot)` would give you:

> **Value:**
>
> A numeric vector (or matrix, when 'beside = TRUE'), say 'mp',
>   giving the coordinates of *all* the bar midpoints drawn, useful
>   for adding to the graph.

So, for `barplot`, it is returning a matrix with the midpoint x values of the five bars:

```
F <- c(2, 4, 5, 7, 4)
bp <- (barplot(F, ylim=c(0,10),
               main="Report Freqencies", xlab="Freqencies", ylab="Number",
               names.arg=c("Daily","Weekly","Monthly", "Quarterly", "Semi-Annual"),
               border="dark green", density=c(70, 70, 70, 70, 70)))
bp
##      [,1]
## [1,]  0.7
## [2,]  1.9
## [3,]  3.1
## [4,]  4.3
## [5,]  5.5
text(bp, F, labels = format(F,5), pos = 3, cex = 0.75)
```